# How to configure expiration password into 12 months?

Tags: passwords, azure-ad-b2c, configure

in [azure-ad-b2c], I have an application connected to it and I'm looking for how to configure the users password for 12 months expiration and I can't find it. If you can help me or any other suggestion to be able to do this. THANKS

I search in my users flow but I don't find where to set expiration password. I find to set token but for password nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting.

B2C passwords don't expire out of the box.

There are some [samples](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master#password-management) to force password reset which you can use to force the password to expire.